# How to get query parameter and an encoded infromation from URI using JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, google-cloud-platform

I have my information appended in URL which follows a format of 2 query parameters and one encoded information. Is there any specific module to get the information from the query parameters or I may have to use split functions ?
Sample : ?xys=2929292&abc=1213123&%5B%7B%22fm%22%3A%2212%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22as-as%22%2C%22pf%22%3A%7B%22nm%22%3A%22cc%22%7D%2C%22tx%22%3A%7B%22bd%22%3A%22Hi%22%7D%2C%22ts%22%3A%221211%22%2C%22ty%22%3A%22tx%22%2C%22wanm%22%3A%2212123%22%7D%5D

I am trying for node server

Sample : ?xys=2929292&abc=1213123&%5B%7B%22fm%22%3A%2212%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22as-as%22%2C%22pf%22%3A%7B%22nm%22%3A%22cc%22%7D%2C%22tx%22%3A%7B%22bd%22%3A%22Hi%22%7D%2C%22ts%22%3A%221211%22%2C%22ty%22%3A%22tx%22%2C%22wanm%22%3A%2212123%22%7D%5D

Expected Output
xys = 2929292
abc = 1213123
message = [{"fm":"12","id":"as-as","pf":{"nm":"cc"},"tx":{"bd":"Hi"},"ts":"1211","ty":"tx","wanm":"12123"}]

Comment: `window.location.query`? Split using `&`? Decode using `decodeURIComponent`?

Comment: Please may you add the efforts you have made so far? Specifically a [mcve]?

Comment: Thanks @evolutionxbox . Sure will try out. As I am newbie would mind sharing a sample code ?

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript/901144#901144

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Try The **Vanila JS**. Like Below

```
document.location.search
```

Answer (score 0):

install `query-string` package from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) and work using it e.g.

```
var const qS = require('query-string');


const parsed = qS.parse(location.search);
console.log(parsed);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your query is wrong, it should be

`?xys=2929292&abc=1213123&message=%5B%7B%22fm%22%3A%2212%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22as-as%22%2C%22pf%22%3A%7B%22nm%22%3A%22cc%22%7D%2C%22tx%22%3A%7B%22bd%22%3A%22Hi%22%7D%2C%22ts%22%3A%221211%22%2C%22ty%22%3A%22tx%22%2C%22wanm%22%3A%2212123%22%7D%5D`

rest of the answer is assuming you are using node server with express

then in node server you can get output from

```
console.log(req.query);
xys = parseFloat(req.query.xys) //remove parseFloat if you want string
abc = parseFloat(req.query.abc)
message = JSON.parse(req.query.message) //JSON.parse() will convert string to array
```